# Rvest - how to collect all titles from forum

Tags: r, matrix, web-scraping, rvest

I have problem with collecting all titles of post on a forum.

```
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url_page <-c("http://medyczka.pl/forum-gastrologiczne/")
all_titles <- matrix()
#Function
for (i in 1:5) {
web <-read_html(paste0(url_page,i))
post_title <- web %>% html_nodes(css='.title') %>%
  html_text() %>%
  as.character()
all_titles <- rbind(all_titles, post_title)
}
#Show me collected titles
str(all_titles)
head(all_titles)
#str(all_titles)
 #chr [1:6, 1] NA "Ból po operacji szczeliny odbytu" "Hemoroidy?" ...
 #- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  #..$ : chr [1:6] "" "post_title" "post_title" "post_title" ...
  #..$ : NULL
```

I should have got 100 rows. However it looks that function collected only title of the first post of each 1-5 pages.
What I have coded wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you've coded wrong, but I'd do this differently.

First, write a function to return titles, given the base url and page number:

(EDITED)

```
get_titles <- function(base_url, page) {
  read_html(paste0(base_url, page)) %>% 
    html_nodes(".title") %>% 
    html_text()
}
```

Now use `purrr::map2_df` to create the data frame using the function:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

titles <- map2_df("http://medyczka.pl/forum-gastrologiczne/", 
                  1:5, 
                  ~tibble(titles = get_titles(.x, .y)))
```

`titles` is now a 1 x 100 data frame with the titles.

```
glimpse(titles)

Observations: 100
Variables: 1
$ titles <chr> "Ból po operacji szczeliny odbytu", 
               "Biegunko podobne coś po kawie, nabial, ostrym jedzeniu", 
               "reg...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to rbind a vector into an empty matrix, R is having a problem knowing what your intentions are.  It is best to define the shape the destination in a clearer manner.  Here I am defining all_titles as data frame and defining post_title as a data frame before the binding.

```
url_page <-c("http://medyczka.pl/forum-gastrologiczne/")
all_titles <- data.frame()
#Function
for (i in 1:5) {
web <-read_html(paste0(url_page,i))
post_title <- web %>% html_nodes(css='.title') %>%
  html_text() 
all_titles <- rbind(all_titles, data.frame(post_title))
}
```

I have not tested this but it should work.  It is not very efficient to use rbind within a loop, but since you loop is only 5 cycles and 100 total elements the performance impact is small.

Just as a reminder, please read the user agreement on this web site and obey any restrictions.

Comment: Nice, this code works very well.  but  what shall I do to make function more efficient If will gather data from hundreds or thousands pages? Is purrr::map2_df more efficient?

Comment: There are multiple ways to improve the performance.  the `map` function is one way.  Pre-allocating the memory space, the `do.call` function on a list are some other.   Search site or see the "R Inferno" for more tips. I will warn against rapidly pinging a web site hundreds of times as this may be deemed as a hacker activity and/or violate the terms of service.